# allShortestPaths: Unknown Identifier

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Im currently writing a query to return a VIRTUEALSUITE with its belonging PRODUCT_VERSIONS and their children (recursively).

Here is my current query:

```
MATCH (vs: VIRTUALSUITE {NAME: "Test VS Copy"})-[:INCLUDES_VERSION]->(productVersion: PRODUCT_VERSION)
MATCH allShortestPaths((productVersion)-[:IS_BOMPARENT_OF*..]->(child: PRODUCT_VERSION))
RETURN vs, productVersion, child
```

I need the "allShortestPaths" function. Otherwise queries like this take an infinite time.

But as a result of this query i just get the error message:

```
Unknown identifier `child`
Unknown identifier `vs`.
Unknown identifier `productVersion`.
Unknown identifier `child`.
```

As u will probably notice, I'm quite new to this. Would be very nice, if you could help me out! :)

Thanks a lot and Greetings
Schakron

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using version 2.0 of neo4j. Your Cypher query should work in versions 2.1 and above.

See [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=fn1cf4). You can change the version used by the console by clicking the Options button at the top.

Also, I believe you would want to return the shortest paths:

```
MATCH (vs: VIRTUALSUITE {NAME: "Test VS Copy"})-[:INCLUDES_VERSION]->(productVersion: PRODUCT_VERSION)
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((productVersion)-[:IS_BOMPARENT_OF*..]->(child: PRODUCT_VERSION))
RETURN vs, productVersion, child, p
```